# Calling a method at the fastest possible interval (timers)

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have a method that I want to run several thousands of times per second. I'm currently running it at a rate of roughly once every millisecond using DispatcherTimer, with the Interval property set to 1ms.

Now, DispatcherTimer isn't the fastest, most high-precision timer available and since the Tick event handler is running on the UI thread it's not going to execute much more often than that. The code I'm calling doesn't need to run on the UI thread so I seems like I'm limiting myself for no real reason.

What are my options if I want a higher frequency? Should I use System.Threading.Timer? Is there a specific Timer for high-frequency, high-precision operations? Should I just forego timers altogether and look into something else?

Note that although I tried (but failed, due to lack of reputation) to tag this as WindowsIot (because I need it to run there and possibly the new Devices library has stuff specifically for this), this applies to .net applications in general as well, be I WPF, WinForms, WinRT, etc...

Comment: What is your goal? Why you need thousands of timers?

Comment: @General-Doomer OP said thousand times. not thousand timers

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What that method is supposed to do?

Comment: There is endless loop: `for(;;)` or `while(true)`

Comment: I have an LPD8806 LED strip that gets updated whenever I call Windows.Devices.Spi.SpiDevice.Write(byte[]). At every Tick, I change a bunch of bytes in an array and then call SpiDevice.Write, changing the LED values. I want to be able to change the LEDs as often as possible. The SpiDevice runs at 20MHz, which is obviously way too fast for a .NET timer to achieve, but I'm wondering if there's not still more to squeeze out of it than the roughly 1KHz I'm getting now.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying problem is that when you yield CPU time, you're doing so in the OS scheduling system. Which means that operations like `Thread.Sleep`, or indeed, waiting for callback of a system timer, are limited by the frequency of the system timer. That's usually 15.6ms - far longer than your 1ms. The way WPF gets around this, to allow smooth animations etc., is that while the animation is proceeding, it will change the global timer frequency. The minimum is 0.5ms which *might* be good enough for you - provided the rest of the code can execute in 0.5ms (for a total of 1ms "frame time"). Obviously, it's a bit tricky to have a reliable frequency.

So this boils down to *why* you're trying to run something exactly 1000 times per second, and *what* you're doing in the cycle.

And you're almost guaranteed *not* to get this kind of resolution. Even if you set the global timer to 0.5ms, and make a `Timer` that executes every second, you'll still be fighting with other threads trying to execute.

One of the approaches used in gaming is using the High-Resolution Timer - `QueryPerformanceCounter`, used internally in `Stopwatch`. However, that doesn't allow you to *yield* - you have to actively spin (unless you can `Thread.Sleep` for long enough to allow you to use this - see above). And note that most games that use fixed step timing - something like your scenario are usually limited to about 60 FPS - almost 17ms per cycle. That's a far cry from 1ms per cycle. When not using fixed step timing, you can actually make a lot of cool stuff, but you have to account for the actual length of the time step - not entirely simple, and possibly not applicable to your case.

Comment: Interesting stuff. I guess I should run some sort of counter in my current code - using DispatcherTimer - to see how often it is -actually- running. Maybe it won't make much of a (perceivable) difference wether I use DispatcherTimer or some other timer after all. I'll report back.

Thanks for the insightful post!

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use an endless loop and do the timing yourself using a `Stopwatch`. This uses the native [rdtsc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twchhe95.aspx) method, which counts the actual CPU cycles. It's much more accurate than other timers in .NET. You could avoid the overhead of Stopwatch and call the native methods [directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx). If calling the native methods, you will probably want to use [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I written some code. Remember, that it is not the best solution, but it works.

Class `FrequencyRunner`:

```
public class FrequencyRunner
{
    private int _frequency;
    private Action _action;
    private bool _isStarted = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// частота
    /// </summary>
    public int Frequency { get { return _frequency; } set { _frequency = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// задача
    /// </summary>
    public Action Action { get { return _action; } set { _action = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// конструктор
    /// </summary>
    public FrequencyRunner()
    {
        _frequency = 1000;
        _action = () => { };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// конструктор
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="frequency"> частота </param>
    /// <param name="action"> задача </param>
    public FrequencyRunner(int frequency, Action action)
    {
        _frequency = frequency;
        _action = action;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// запустить процесс
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        _isStarted = true;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            double interval = 1000 / _frequency;

            while (_isStarted)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                _action();
                sw.Stop();

                double timeLeft = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                if (timeLeft < interval)
                {
                    // need wait some time...
                    sw.Restart();
                    timeLeft = interval - timeLeft;
                    while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < timeLeft)
                    {
                        // nothing to do
                    }
                    sw.Stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// завершить процесс
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        _isStarted = false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// run it for 2 seconds (25 times per second)
int i = 0;
var runner = new FrequencyRunner(25, () => Console.WriteLine("Counter: {0}", ++i));
runner.Start();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
runner.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

As Luaan mentions, you're at the mercy of the OS if you use Sleep.

If calling on a precise interval is important to you, then [SpinWait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) and SpinUntil is what you want. Note that this will continue to execute code until the condition/timers are satisfied, and therefore your thread will occupy 100% of the CPU time on the core that you're executing on. (If you're on a 4 core machine, you'll see 25% CPU Usage).

**This will not guarantee that you will execute exactly when you want** - the OS is still free to steal CPU time and schedule other threads to execute.  The only way to guarantee execution on an exact interval is to use a [Realtime OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) like VxWorks. This has guarantees in place to ensure specified allocation of cpu time.  Of course, a RTOS won't run .NET - so you'd have to use a different language.